# (Potential Bug) Why what I copy and save from Visual Studio code doesn't match the results?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, editor

Here is My Code:

VSCode shows the following, and the editor is supposed to.

```c
if(player.stamina> 0 && player.cont_t>= 60) player.stamina= 8;
if(!player.stamina && player.cont_t>= 30) {
    // ...
}
```

That's what it is supposed to show and what VSCode shows. But when I saved, or Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C to copy, the code had become: (it is what really being saved)

```c
if(player.stamina > 0 && player.cont_t >= 66) player.stamina= 8;
if(!player.stamina && player.cont_t>= 24) {
    // ...
}
```

If I save the file **in VSCode**, VSCode shows the "new" version, but what is really being saved is the "old" version.

If I edit and save it in **Notepad**, it works correctly, however, this is not the case for **VSCode**. It still shows the `out-of-sync` version. Also, I tried to edit other files in the same folder — in **VSCode** — it is correctly saved.

When I try to copy using the keybindings <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it is still `out-of-sync`. I am very confused, it works as expected when I manually select this part of code to copy. Do you know any reason why these are happening? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself and VSCode did not format my code.
So this has to be a IDE Settings, you should check under `File -> Preferences -> Settings` and search for `format`.

There are two checkboxes you need to uncheck, which are `"Format On Paste"` and `"Format On Save"`, see here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it isn't where the problem lies. It is the file being "cursed" in some way. Only the shown part in my question is out-of-sync. When I wrote other stuff into the problematic file, it shows in other text editor as well, but the "cursed" part is "refreshed" in vscode (i.e. it became an older version). VSCode just doesn't save my edits to that particular part, but it somehow thinks it do.